# Upgrading from spark 1.6 to 2.4.x , spark sql sort merge join leads to dip in performance as data in cassandra grows

Tags: apache-spark

Upgrading from spark 1.6 to 2.4.x , spark sql sort merge join between two DataSet1 and DataSet2 leads to dip in performance as data in cassandra grows for Dataset2, seems DataSet1 is doing full table scan to join with other Dataset2 which leads to lot of shuffling and hence as data grows in DB for Dataset2 , same Dataset1 joining is taking more time than earlier.

```
Dataset<Row> dataset1 = mySession.read().format(org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra).options(new HashMap<String, String>(){ 
  put(KEYSPACE, keySpace);
  put(TABLE, table1);
}}).load().where("key in "+criteria);

Dataset<Row> dataset2 = mySession.read().format(org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra).options(new HashMap<String, String>(){ 
  put(KEYSPACE, keySpace);
  put(TABLE, table2);
}}).load();

Dataset<SchemaLess> theJoinedDataset= dataset1.join(dataset2, dataset1.col("joinkey").equalTo(dataset2.col("key"))
```

Please respond if anybody has idea related to this.